# Does CSS have a rule against trailing zeros?

Tags: css, jsfiddle

Is writing a property in the form `width: 90.0%;` non-valid CSS, or is that some rule that JSFiddle made up?

Comment: [That rule](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/number-no-trailing-zeros/README.md) might be a performance recommendation, similar to [disallowing units for zero values in CSSLint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-units-for-zero-values) or [StyleLint](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/length-zero-no-unit/). In the words of [Matt Wilcox](https://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1054/), "don’t blindly follow the crap these tools tell you".

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I think it would take Ruby longer to evaluate `(x.denominator == 1 ? "%d" : "%f") % x` than it would take Firefox et al. to trip over a speed bump due to not following a performance recommendation. But I do strive to appease W3C Validator.

Comment: That does seem likely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the CSS BNF (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/) that should be legal.

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#percentage-token-diagram
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#number-token-diagram